# Download Java Class File & Run?

Tags: java

Okay, so pretty much I'm trying to add security to my Java class file. I don't want it to get decompiled. So what I've done is created a login system where the java app checks it through a web request. If the login information is correct then it will run the script. However, I want to further improve security and have the class file hosted online.

How can I make it download & run the online hosted file?

Also, when the app/script stops running or it's closed the .class file is deleted.

I'd prefer where it did not have to download the file, just get from an online server and compile/run.

Comment: tldr - After the login is good,  how would I get the script to make a call or  execute another class file hosted online?

Comment: This is a vague question that might have more than solution. To me it reads like looking for a clunky technical solution to a conceptual problem.

Comment: @madth3 It's not really vague, just badly phrased, but it *might* be an instance of the XY problem as the notion is strictly defined. That said, as the question stands it's perfectly answerable, while discussing the conceptual problem would make it a off topic.

Comment: @Vernard You should consider editing out the clutter about the login and the temporary file being deleted etc. It doesn't really matter exactly how you get the `.class` file or what happens to it when you're done with it, and it is confusing to have most of your post talk about something else than your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) (the "default" Java classloader) and point it at wherever you saved the file:

```
// the directory where you're saving the .class file
File tmpDir = new File("/tmp/yadda/blah/");
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { tmpDir.toURI().toURL() }, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass("SuperSecretClass");
// use reflection to instantiate cls, call methods, etc.
```

(Passing in the parent class loader might not be necessary in a non-webapp, but I'm too lazy to test that detail. Using the thread's classloader explicitly will work one way or the other.

This assumes that your secret class is not in a package, if it is you'll have to create the appropriate directory structure inside the temporary directory and point the classloader at the root of the package tree, as usual.

Also: this sort of security-by-obscurity sounds like a bad idea. You're still downloading the file, if it's over an unsecured connection a determined attacker can sniff it, and there's still the period of time during which it's on disk. You *could* create a completely custom `ClassLoader` that directly reads the stream, but even the class file could probably be recovered with a little more effort. (Like pointing a debugger at your main app and intercepting stream reads.) The [javadoc for `ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) provides an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Let's go through the things you have done, and the things you are proposing to do and see if they will really work:

- Asking for a password.  This is easily to defeat:

  1. Capture the classfile.
  2. Decompile it.
  3. Identify the place where it makes the remote call does the login check, and checks the response.
  4. Modify the bytecodes to remove all of that.
- Rather than installing the class file, download it on demand and delete it when it finishes.  Also easy to defeat.

  1. Capture network request made to download the file.
  2. Replay the request using (say) `curl` or `wget` and capture the downloaded class file.
  3. Proceed as above.

And variations are relatively easy to defeat too:

- Obfuscation can always ultimately be defeated by **manual** decompilation and/or running the bytecodes using a debugger.
- Downloading using one-time key or something can be defeated by reverse engineering the procedure and extracting the one-time key ... before it is used.
- Encrypting the bytecodes can defeated because the JVM has to have the bytecodes in decrypted form at some point.  So the means of decryption of the bytecodes must be embedded in code ... that can be reverse engineered.

---

The bottom line is that it is impossible to prevent a skilled and determined person from defeating security schemes that depend on keeping things secret from a user who controls his / her own execution platform.

The best you can hope to do is stop low-skilled attackers, and slow down skilled ones.  You need to ask yourself ... is it really worth the effort?

(Note: you have the same problem no matter what implementation language you use.)